# Display the results of a query in a qml list

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have connected my c++ classes with the qml ui like this:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/App/main.qml")));

qmlRegisterSingletonType<SessionManager>("AppManager", 0, 1, "SessionManager", SessionManager::qmlSingleton);
```

I can return simple results like strings or numbers with success, but what I want to do now is to be able to display in a list the results of a `SELECT` statement on my database.

What should I return from my c++ method and how should I manage it on the qml part, can someone provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

You've a few alternatives.

1. You can subclass [`QSqlQueryModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html) and implement something like is in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839386/how-to-assign-sql-query-output-model-from-qt-to-qmls-tableview)
2. You can use `QxORM`, a Qt/C++ ORM and connect it to the QML view, they've a simple example on their [faq](http://www.qxorm.com/qxorm_en/faq.html#faq_300)
3. If you just want to display the output of a Sqlite query, you can use a library that I've made that's a simple ORM for QML/Sqlite, you can clone from the [repository](https://github.com/danielfranca/quickmodel) and check how to use it from the [docs](http://quickmodel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: For the moment I decided to test the first suggestion, since not having to include any libraries sounds more appealing. After subclassing `QSqlQueryModel` in the linked answer the values are passed using `engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty` whereas I am using `qmlRegisterSingletonType`. Should I go ahead and set the model to the rootContext?